# What is the best/most correct way to iterate through the characters of a string in ESQL?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

What is the best/most correct way to iterate through the characters of a string in ESQL?

In Java I would do like this but how do I do it in esql?

```
String s = "...stuff...";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);        
    //Process char }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the characters?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE text CHAR 'asdf';
DECLARE TOTAL INT;
DECLARE count INT 1;
SET TOTAL = LENGTH(text);

WHILE count <= TOTAL DO
    DECLARE c CHAR;
    SET c = SUBSTRING(text FROM count FOR 1);

    SET count = count + 1;
END WHILE;
```